# windows author information properties

Tags: lua

How can I input all the author information for a windows lua made app?

So that when you right click -- properties it it will show or fill out all that information?

Can I do that from lua?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you make a Windows application out of a Lua script? Lua is an interpreted language, so it must use an executable somewhere to load it. Typically, it is done with Lua.exe. If you have a specially-made executable for your Lua app, then you can just set those properties on that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

But I meant after I compile it into an exe, where can I set up all those properties?

I am guessing I will have to input it into the script somehow and than have it compile that part correctly so it shows up in the windows properties, right? Something alike.

Comment: So this really has nothing to do with Lua at all; you have an executable that just so happens to use some Lua scripts. This is a question about Win32 executables, not Lua. Please change the question and its tags accordingly.

Comment: Well it is not compiled yet but yes a lua app. I referred to lua because in for example VB you can set it within VB itself, that is why I asked.

But I guess you are shifting to a Win32 executable and know a different way to set it, without its original lua code?

Comment: That's because it's _Microsoft_ Visual Basic. The kinds of properties you're talking about are unique to _Windows_ executables. That's not a question of them being good or bad; it's just platform specific. And standard Lua doesn't have any platform specific features.

Comment: OK. But is there a way to fill out those properties?

Or do I have to do it through some windows tool as you above suggested, I think?

Comment: I'm sure there is. But if you want to know _how_, then you should change your question to ask exactly that. And change the tags on your question so that you can find actual Windows developers who might be able to tell you how to do this. And it won't be done from Lua.

Answer (score 0):

Lua itself have no relation to any platform-specific binary file tags. The tool you use to pack Lua scripts to Windows executable may have some some built-in methods to read this tool-specific tags from your sources and thus you should consult its documentation (or at very least post what exactly do you use).

Failing that, you can edit resources manually following information on MSDN:

- [Executable's Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632583%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [Modifying the resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648004%28VS.85%29.aspx)

There's also numerous GUI or command-line tools for the job: just search your favorite search engine for "portable executable resource editor".